# R user defined function, return multiple type objects

Tags: r, list, user-defined-functions

I have a user-defined function in R which returns a list, I also want that function to return a variable (numeric) which holds the count value. Any idea as to how should I proceed with returning a list as well as a numeric variable?

Comment: Can you return a nested list? I.e. `list(original_list, variable)`? Or you can just add the variable as a named element in the list that you return

Comment: I already tried this and it changes the structure of the list, I don't want the numeric variable to be in form of a list. Is it possible in R?

Comment: Two options: 1) look at the `zeallot` package, 2) set `attributes` of your list.

Comment: To expand on the comment by @thc, `attr(original_list, "count") <- length(original_list)`.

Answer (score 0):

Include that numeric variable the list which is returned by the function